# what is [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, jquery

why instead giving data(value) of database give me the [object Object]?

```
var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: dataObj,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $(".list_name").show().html('');
                $(".list_name").append('<p><a href="" id="result">' + data + '</a></p>');
                $('.list_name p a').click( function(e) {
                                e.preventDefault();
                                $('<b>' + b + '، </b><input type="text" name="hotel[]" value="' + b + '" style="border: none; display: none;" />').appendTo($('.auto_box span'));
                                $(this).remove();
                            return false;
                            });
            });
```

results url is:(json_encode()) :

```
[{"name":"333333"},{"name":"\u0633\u0644"},{"name":"\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0633\u06cc"},{"name":"\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0633\u0633"},{"name":"\u0633\u0644\u0627\u0645"}]
```

update: full code:

```
$('.auto_complete').keyup(function () {
        var id = '#' + this.id;
        var alt = $(id).attr('alt'); var id = $(this).attr('id'); var name = $(this).attr('name');
        var url = alt + id + '/' + name;
    var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: dataObj,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $(".list_name").show().html('');
        for (i in data) {
            var obj = $('<a href="" id="result">' + data[i].name + '</a>');
            obj.click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('<b>' + b + '، </b><input type="text" name="hotel[]" value="' + b + '" style="border: none; display: none;" />').appendTo($('.auto_box span'));
                            $(this).remove();
                        return false;
                        });
             var p = $('p');
             p.append(obj);
             $(".list_name").append(p);
        }
   },
        "error": function (x, y, z) {
            // callback to run if an error occurs
            alert("An error has occured:\n" + x + "\n" + y + "\n" + z);
        }
        });

    });
```

Comment: Because `data` is an `Object`, not an `Array`. I'm not very familiar with this aspect of jQuery, but you could try using `data.toString()`.

Comment: how must getting data(value) instead  [object Object]?

Comment: huh? I cannot comprehend your meaning.

Comment: if i want displaying all names together, how is it?(loop)(not want use of .each())

Answer (score 0):

data is a list (It is javascript object).
`toString( list )` in javascript gives "object Object"

data[0].name will return "333333"

To make a string from a complex object write your own function.

Answer (score 0):

data is not a string, but a [JSON](http://json.org/) object, which is basically a Javascript Object. You access it as you would any JS object/array (looks like your result string is an array)

So you can do something like this: `data[1].name`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your Ajax call is returning an array of structures. Each element in the array is a name-value pair. Given that data is an array, the first element is data[0] so you might do something like:

```
var firstElem = data[0];
var firstName = firstElem.name;
alert("The first name is: " + firstName);
```

If you want to add all of the names into your html, you would need to loop through the array, each time appending the current element.

If you wanted to show all names, you could do

```
var names = "";

for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
   var elem = data[i];
   names = names + elem.name + ", ";   
}
```

Comment: if i want displaying all names together, how is it?(loop)(not want use of .each())

Comment: I'm not sure if the edit above addresses your question, it loops through and creates a comma separated list of names.

Comment: thank you, how must puting each which separate in tag a<a></a>?(appendTo)

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite it in the following way

```
var dataObj = $(this).closest('form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: dataObj,
    cache: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $(".list_name").show().html('');
        for (i in data) {
            var obj = $('<a href="" id="result">' + data[i].name + '</a>');
            obj.click(function(e) {
                            e.preventDefault();
                            $('<b>' + b + '، </b><input type="text" name="hotel[]" value="' + b + '" style="border: none; display: none;" />').appendTo($('.auto_box span'));
                            $(this).remove();
                        return false;
                        });
             var p = $('p');
             p.append(obj);
             $(".list_name").append(p);
        }
   }
});
```

Comment: this not displaying results search?

Comment: i update full code to Ask. please see it and call, what is problem?

Comment: Is .list_name unique identifier? Presented only once in the page?

Comment: please see this link and click on image +, and go to filde "insert hotel" and type any of this word: salsh, salasi, salaso, salal, 333333
http://www.binboy.gigfa.com/auto/

Comment: problem is appendTo and click on search results that put several results.

Comment: document.getElementById("clock") is null. And I don't know what to search for to get any results?

Comment: type any of this words: salsh, salasi, salaso, salal, 333333

Comment: to filde "insert hotel" no filter. click on image +